# Issue when trying to query a MongoDB data

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a document in a collection that has the following attributes:

```
nodeid : long
type: string
bagid: long
```

So, nodes can be on a bag, and be of different types.

I need to find,
all nodes of type A, *or* nodes of type B in a given list of nodes, *or*, nodes of type C in a given bag.

How can I design that query in MongoDB? I had all IN clauses but it is the works way to go performance wise. Could you please point me into the right direction? I could not find an aggregation or reduce that would help me make this simpler.

I tried also doing a text search, using the three elements, but the or in the text search, for instance "type: A \"type: B node:X\" \"type: B node: Y\" and so on, does not work.

Thanks

Edit, adding samples:

```
{ "_id" : BinData(3,"NJUuYHEBAAAdCda3V+kXvg=="), 
"type" : "question", "bagid" : NumberLong(1067), 
"topics" : [ NumberLong(33), NumberLong(67), NumberLong(203), NumberLong(217) ], 
"nodeid" : NumberLong(15855), 
"creationDate" : ISODate("2020-04-09T18:23:17.812Z"),
"_class" : "com.test.NodeEvent" }

{ "_id" : BinData(3,"NJUuYHEBAAAdCda3V+kXvg=="), 
"type" : "comment", "bagid" : NumberLong(1067), 
"topics" : [ NumberLong(33), NumberLong(67), NumberLong(203), NumberLong(217) ], 
"nodeid" : NumberLong(15857), 
"creationDate" : ISODate("2020-04-09T18:23:17.812Z"),
"_class" : "com.test.NodeEvent" }

{ "_id" : BinData(3,"NJUuYHEBAAAdCda3V+kXvg=="), 
"type" : "question", "bagid" : NumberLong(1069), 
"topics" : [ NumberLong(33), NumberLong(67) ], 
"nodeid" : NumberLong(15859), "creationDate" : ISODate("2020-04-09T18:23:17.812Z"),
"_class" : "com.test.NodeEvent" }
```

Comment: could you explain it more, add some samples from your data, add the given lists of nodes that you need type B to be in, and so on?

Comment: @MohammedYousry Added samples, the query would be something like, given bag 1067 give me all nodes with topics: 33 or 203

Comment: Also could be, give me all comments. 
Or give me all Questions or comments in bags 1060, 1067, 2054
And so on

Answer (score 0):

You can build your queries using the MongoDB Query Language. The query is written using the [db.collection.find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/index.html) method. It uses various query operators like, [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/index.html), [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/index.html), and [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/index.html).

> I need to find, all nodes of type A, or nodes of type B in a given
>   list of nodes, or, nodes of type C in a given bag. How can I design
>   that query in mongo?

```
db.collection.find( { $or: [ 
                             { type: "A" },  
                             { type: "B", node: { $in: [ "A", "C" ] },
                             { type: "C", bag: 130 }
                           ]  
} );
```

In the above query the *condition* `{ type: "C", bag: 130 }` is equivalent to `{ $and: [ { type: "C" }, { bag: 130 } ] } }`. This is also the case with the condition `{ type: "B", node: { $in: [ "A", "C" ] }`. But, using the `$and` is optional, in this case (see the documentation for details).

> The query would be something like, given bag 1067 give me all nodes
>   with topics: 33 or 203

```
db.collection.find( { bag: 1067, topics: { $in: [ 33, 203 ] } } )
```

The output depends upon the data in the collection. The `find` method returns a *cursor*, and you can apply various [cursor methods](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/js-cursor/index.html) on the retrned documents (for example, you can sort them by a field).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I have tried that, the main issue, is that when the collection gets big, more tan 100k items, and the node count gets over 20, the type count can be of around 5 elements, and the bag count over 20 as well, then the query takes more than 1/2 min to recover data. I have tried limiting using dates, but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you specify what your query (or queries) are? The query performance depends upon many factors, but mainly we define indexes on the queried fields to make the query run fast. So, defining index or indexes can help (especially where number of documents are in 100k+). See documentation on [Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/index.html).